# add a attribute to sales/order model in magento in product environment

Tags: php, magento, attributes, addition

I want add a attribute to order,the following steps is works in the test environment,but not works in product environment ,there is a difference between the two environments,the product env is  implement database Master-slave separation,but test env not .
steps: 
1.because in the database table *core_resource*  is 
`code;| version`
`sales_setup|0.9.40`
so I modified the file /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml
     `<modules>`  
 
     `<Mage_Sales>` 
     `<version>0.9.41</version>` 
     `</Mage_Sales>` 
     `...`
     `</modules>`  
2.add a file /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.40-0.9.41.php 
the content is :
`$installer = $this;` 
`$installer->addAttribute('order', 'prx', array(`
`'type'          => 'varchar',`
`'backend_type'  => 'varchar',`
`'frontend_input' => 'varchar',`
 `'is_user_defined' => true,`
 `'label'         => 'prx',`
`'visible'       => true,`
 `'required'      => false,`
 `'user_defined'  => false,`
 `'searchable'    => false,`
`'filterable'    => false,`
`'comparable'    => false,`
`'default'       => ''`
`));`

who can tell me why,thanks!

if the script is just add a record in the table ***eav_attribute***?can I add the record by a sql script instead?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the Magento version. Starting with version 1.4.0.1 the sales tables are not eav anymore. They are simple flat tables. You can add any column you want to `sales_flat_order` table. The update script you found as example is before version 1.4, that's why it has that look.